# htaccess redirect to subfolder with a trailing slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I successfully managed to redirect all requests to a subfolder of my web server.

This is the code I'm using:

### /.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

### /public/.htaccess

```
# redirect all urls that doesn’t have a 
# trailing slash to urls with a trailing slash
# (this is my try)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NC]
```

It works perfectly, so the following redirects work:

```
example.com                 -> example.com/public/
example.com/foo/            -> example.com/public/foo/
example.com/foo/about.html  -> example.com/public/foo/about.html
```

By the way, the following redirect has a problem:

```
example.com/foo             -> example.com/public/foo
```

Although it redirects correctly, the actual URL in the address bar is:

```
example.com/public/foo/
```

So my question is:

#### How can I have a *clean URL* when redirecting from a URL without a forward slash?

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: `/public/foo/` is an actual directory; `/foo/` isn't.

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't clear enough; I just want a clean url (without `public`), I don't care about the trailing slash. Actually with my "try" I attempted to *add* a trailing slash to the actual folder, hoping that it would then redirect to a clean url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1/ [L]
```

Then just remove `/public/.htaccess` since that is not needed.